# How can I let the user activate a particular SuperSort filter

Tags: filter, plugin-supersort, link

***I have just realised I am mixing up my filtering and sorting. I have amended the question to try and make it a bit clearer.

I'm trying to use SuperSort plugin to run different filters, but I'm struggling as only the last filter gets applied. I would like to add the filter to a button or link, so that when the user clicks on it, it activates the filter. Any tips?

```
<h1>search</h1>

<form action="{{ url('search') }}">
    <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set users = craft.users.search(query).order('dateUpdated')|reverse %}

{% if users|length %}
    <p></p>
    <ul>
        <span<a href="{{ users.dateUpdated }}">{{ users|length }} results:</a></span>
        <li><a href="{% set usersByFirstName = craft.users.search('sortAS', '{{ firstName}}') %}">A-Z</a></li>

        <li><a href="{% set users = craft.users.search(query).order('firstName')|reverse%}">Z-A</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Nearby</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Newest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Oldest</a></li>
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

For example:

link#1 - sort A-Z
link#2 - sort dateUpdated

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit more? I am not sure what information you are looking for. Thanks!

Comment: The filters are currently overwriting each other, so only the last filter applies. I'd like to use different filters like this:
link#1 - filter A-Z
link#2 - filter dateUpdated
Hope that makes more sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in order to do this you have to reformat your code and your strategy a bit. You cant provide a Craft query as a link, all that does is grab an array from the database and it won't inherently print something out.

```
<li><a href="{% set usersByFirstName = craft.users.search('sortAS', '{{ firstName}}') %}">A-Z</a></li>
```

The best way to change the way your results are being sorted (if you want to do it via Twig and not something front-end like JS is to send the sort style through a query string.

So let's assume you are returning a list of users and you want to sort them by first name alpha ascending:

```
{% set users = craft.users.order('firstName asc').find() %}
```

If you want to change the direction of the order create a link like this:

```
<a href="url/user-list?sort=desc">Sort Z-A</a>
```

When the page reloads a new query parameter is available to you `sort`, you can get it with this code:

```
{% set sort = craft.request.getParam('sort') %}
```

Now you can use that variable to alter the way your original query works. Something like this... starting over from scratch:

```
{% if craft.request.getParam('sort')|length > 0 %}

    {% set sort = craft.request.getParam('sort') %}

 {% else %}

    {% set sort = 'asc' %} {# default sort #}

 {% endif %}
```

Then in the Craft query, you could just user this instead of our original query above:

```
 {% set users = craft.users.order('firstName ' ~ sort).find() %}
```

Now when the page first loads you will get users sorted by `firstName asc` and when you click the filter it will reload with `firstName desc`.

You can apply this same query string method to all of the parameters. Getting variables like:

```
{% set sortBy = craft.request.getParam('sortBy') %}
```

Where `sortBy` equals `firstName` or `lastName`

That query string would look like:

```
url/user-list?sort=desc&sortby=firstName
```

And so on.